# Problem with referencing an external file from the default package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having problems with Eclipse assigning a root java program to the "default package", and as a result, not being able to reference the contents of a file that is also in the root of the program directory, and as a result, I get an exception stating... "No such file or directory"...; yet when I run the same java application in CodeRunner with no changes it works...

To test and demonstrate this:

1. Here is a screen shot of the src folder:

[image]

Ignore all other files and folders except 'TestProgram.java' and 'TestProgramFile.txt'

2. Here is my source code for 'TestProgram.java'...
   [image]
3. Here is the contents of the "TestProgramFile.txt" source file...
   [image]
4. Running 'TestProgram.java' in CodeRunner I get the following...
   [image]
5. Running the same program in Eclipse [Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
   Build id: 20201210-1552].. I get an exception where it cannot file the file...

[image]

What Gives? Is there a setting I need to configure in Eclipse to supress the default package, or do I have to provide a path from the default package from TestProgram.java to TestProgramFile.txt??

Comment: Right-click on your Project and then select 'refresh'. This may help. The other problem could be cause by your run configuration (the small dropdown arrow next to the Run button in the icon menu bar). Is that has manually assigned another path, this might cause the problem. To see where java is currently running, call `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` or something alike, so you see in what directoy your app runs. It does NOT play a role in what package your classes are! No matter in what sub-package, accessing relative files on the file system always gets the same result!

Comment: Another idea is to check `new File(".").getCanonicalPath()` which might resolve symbolic links etc.

Comment: Oh, I see now... you put the files into the src folder... this might be the reasons you cannot access them. Shift them up one folder into the parent/project folder. When they lie in die project folder they should be available like you try to access them. A bit off-topic, but when you try to access files that lie someplace in the source code/package folders, and maybe even get packed into a .jar-file, consider using `getClass().getResource()` and the like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html